# How to continue the download if it did not get complete over even after a long time and closing or canceling the download?

Tags: android, download

I have an application which has a button to start downloading a file and it works completely with no problem.

Now I want to do something more. If the download did not get complete (not overed or finished) or it canceled by user or other things (like losing internet connection), then again user click on the starting download button, the download should start from the continuation of the file but sadly it removes the file and start from the beginning of downloading the file.

What should I do to continue it and not starting again from the beginning?

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog pddDialog;
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
    private Button startinstall;
    private DownloadTask downloadTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutmain);

final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    Button bdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downdata);
    bdd.setTypeface(tf);
    bdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(anim);
            File filedata = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/areasoft/dpei.cso");
            if (filedata.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "you have downloaded  the file completly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                if (ni == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, " you are not connecting to the internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    downloadTask = new DownloadTask(Main.this);
                    downloadTask.execute("download link");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type:
            pddDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pddDialog.setMessage("downloading file…");
            pddDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pddDialog.setMax(100);
            pddDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pddDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pddDialog.setButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    pddDialog.dismiss();
                    downloadTask.cancel(true);
                }
            });
            pddDialog.show();
            return pddDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }
    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // HTTP 200 OK
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/areasoft/dpei.cso");

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;

                if (fileLength > 0)
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

        pddDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The result you are trying to achieve requires special handling from both server and client. Downloadable files are usually divided into small chunks that can be added/merged once all chunks are downloaded.